# bootstrap nested column not working

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a container with nested columns. But now the columns are listed one by one below.

I have fiddled the problem.

Just have a look.

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/xrhprup8/)

I want to display the `Amazon icon` and the text under the icon in the same line. How to achieve that. I have tried a lot but no result. Somebody, please help me. Thankyou.

Comment: For making nested column, you should wrap inside a row. For eg: container --> Column --> Row --> Column --> Row --> Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle if you are looking something like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/xrhprup8/1/

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 full">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 full">
                    <div class="single-box-flipkart">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <h1><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-2x"></i></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <h4>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```